# How to Convert string to JSON Object?

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization

I am using following code to deserailze the JSON data from Url.
 But My Error is:Value {"InvoiceNo":18} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.My Json Like: "{\"InvoiceNo\":18}"    Please Any one Help me.

```
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask{
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(
                    "http://192.168.1.2/Json/api/test"));
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String responseText = null;
        try {
            responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();


        }
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseText); // **Error on this line**
            Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();

            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                String value = null;
                try {
                    value = json.getString(key);
                    Toast.makeText(Billing.this, value + "",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 textInvoice.setText(value.toString());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("responseText", responseText);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: not valid JSON then?

Comment: I have already checked this is valid json and hardcode this json string works fine  @ScaryWombat

Comment: print out the value of `responseText` before `new JSONObject(responseText);`

Comment: My print out value is:responseText: "{\"InvoiceNo\":18}"  @ScaryWombat

Comment: I do not understand what quotes are involved.

Comment: Seems like it is encoding problem.Server must have returned some unseen characters. check the actual value of `responseText`

Comment: If hardcoding the JSON string works fine, then naturally the problem is with the response json, which is not valid json. From your comment, it seems like the server is escaping the quotes in the json.

Answer (score 1):

Your String should not contain the character `"\"`. If so, this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I know I should post comments rather than an answer. But I don't have enough reputations to do so : (              Sorry for that.

Comment: Reviewers please check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag/185074#185074 before deciding

Comment: @WeizhouHe: Please don't misuse answers for other purposes if you don't have enough reputation yet. Anyway, if you think that you have found the problem, then please don't let your answer sound like a clarification question. Please do it similar to Tunaki, who edited your answer.